# Using findall to create list of lists

Tags: prolog

My goal is to print the list of lists containing results of query. `solution` is defined

```
solution(G, T) :- comb(G, T), allPos(T, G), not(cycle(T)), writeln(T), false.
```

and the output looks like this:

```
?- solution([a-b,a-c,a-d,b-c,c-d],X0).
[c-d]
[c-d]
[c-d]
[b-c]
[b-c]
[b-c]
[b-c,c-d]
[b-c,c-d]
[b-c,c-d]
[b-c,c-d]
[b-c,c-d]
.
.
.(etc...)
```

What I got created so far looks like:

```
findall_call(Input, X) :-
  findall(X0, solution(Input, X0), X).
```

, which convert the output of `solution(...)` into following form:

```
?- findall_call(X0, solution([a-b,a-c,a-d,b-c,c-d],X0), X).
[c-d]
[c-d]
[c-d]
[b-c]
[b-c]
[b-c]
[b-c,c-d]
[b-c,c-d]
[b-c,c-d]
.
.
.
X = [].
```

So yeah, the same thing with `X = [].` at the end. Expected output should look like list of lists:

```
[[c-d],[c-d],[c-d],[b-c],[b-c],[b-c],[b-c,c-d],[b-c,c-d],[b-c,c-d]...]
```

Any ideas why does that works so weird? I got feeling the part `, writeln(T), false.` is not really good idea. The reason why I put it there is because I don't want to use semicolon repeatedly to receive all the Prolog's answers. When I delete this part, the output is:

```
?- findall_call(X0, solution([a-b,a-c,a-d,b-c,c-d],X0), X).
X = [[c-d], [c-d], [c-d], [b-c], [b-c], [b-c], [b-c, ... - ...], [... - ...|...], [...|...]|...].
```

which is obviously not my goal.

How should I rework my code to get whole list of lists of

Comment: `writeln` goes right to the output. That's not a result returned to findall. You aren't instantiating `X0` with solutions at all. Don't use `writeln` to show solutions. Instantiate `X0`: `solution(G, T) :- comb(G, T), allPos(T, G), not(cycle(T)).` Then when you call `solution(..., X)` it will show you all of the solutions for `X`. Then your `findall` will make sense.

Comment: @TomasBy Isn't that `^` a typo? By the way, the updated solution in your previous comment- without `, writeln(T), false` is noticed in a question (lots of brackets and dots).

Comment: @TomasBy Well, I of course did, gives me this error `ERROR: Undefined procedure: (^)/2
ERROR:   ^/2 can only appear as the 2nd argument of setof/3 and bagof/3
ERROR: In:
` I run it like : `?- findall(X,[a-b,a-c,a-d,b-c,c-d]^solution([c-b,a-c,c-a,b-a,b-d],X),Xs).`

Comment: @TomasBy You are right, I just updated the question and added whole code.

Comment: @lurker I just updated the question and added whole code. Hope this will happen to make thing clear.

Comment: Do this: `findall(X,solution([a-b,a-c,a-d,b-c,c-d],X),Xs), write(Xs), nl.`

Comment: @TomasBy Sure, that's it. Sorry for misunderstanding, I didn't realize it. Thanks.